# Why am I not able to receive emails from other Wi-Fi networks when using the Java Mail API on Android?

Tags: java, android, api, email

I am new to Android. I am not receiving emails when sent from a different Wi-Fi network, but I am receiving emails when sent from mobile data and from my own Wi-Fi network. Is there a solution to this?

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Comment: is there a firewall on this other network?

Comment: Actually i am making an android application where i will receive the mail but gmail is only recognizing my ip and network and its blocking other networks i tried from 3 other various networks but not receiving any mail

Comment: Is the other WiFi network connected to the Internet?

Comment: and about firewall i dont know

Comment: @11thdimension yes its connected

Comment: is there any authentication for using on all servers?